# ¿ C# Como guardar un metodo en una variable para ser llamada mas adelante?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo el siguiente metodo en una clase C#

```
void Mimetodo(string parametro1, string parametro2)
{
   // Código del metodo
}

void Mimetodo2(int parametro1)
{
   // Código del metodo
}
```

y ahora lo que quiero es igualar ese metodo a una variable para hacer una llamada mas adelante por ejemplo algo así:

```
va = Mimetodo("5", "4");
vb = Mimetodo2(3);
if (opcion == "1") v = vb;
if (opcion == "2") v = va;
v; // Esto seria una llamada a la función que toca.
```

Es decir quiero guardar la referencia a la llamada de esa funcion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una opción es usar el delegado [Action](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0), que permite encapsular un método.

```
Action<string, string> funcion = MimeTodo;
            
funcion("hola", "mundo"); // Esta es la llamada a la función MimeTodo con los parámetros especificados
```

Sin embargo, tendrás que pasar igualmente los parámetros a la instancia de Action.

Para evitar esto, podemos usar una expresión lambda.

```
Action funcion = () => MimeTodo("hola", "mundo");

funcion(); // Esta es la llamada a la función lambda, que a su vez ejecuta el método MimeTodo
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto !

Comment: Buena respuesta, solo por mencionar, también puede usar  el delegado [Func](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.func-2?view=net-5.0) `Func<string, string>`

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Nota previa: había añadido esta respuesta sin darme cuenta de que @JhonRM ya había proporcionado la respuesta correcta. He estado a punto de eliminarla al verlo, pero voy a dejarla dado que aquí explico un poco también el uso de `Func` en contraposición a `Action`, lo que considero que puede ser útil a un futuro usuario con una duda similar. Pido por favor que no se vote positivamente, la respuesta correcta ya la dio JhonRM y el merece los votos positivos.</sub>

Esta es una pregunta interesante. En versiones antiguas del compilador, podrías hacerlo usando [delegados](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates), pero desde hace tiempo el lenguaje posee algo que puede encajar en lo que pides: [`Action`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.action?view=net-5.0) y [`Func`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.func-1?view=net-5.0)

Segun la documentación:

> Action encapsula un método que no tiene parámetros y no devuelve un valor.

y sobre `Func` (hay varias firmas, esta sería una definición general):

> Encapsula un método y devuelve un valor del tipo especificado por el parámetro TResult.

Combinando estos delegados con lambdas, es relativamente sencillo conseguir lo que pides. Te pongo un ejemplo con ambos:

```
static string Mimetodo(string parametro1, string parametro2)
{
    return parametro1 + " "+ parametro2;
}

static void Mimetodo2(string parametro1, string parametro2)
{
    Console.WriteLine(parametro1 + " "+ parametro2);
}
```

Aqui definimos dos metodos, uno con valor devuelto y el otro de tipo `void`. Ahora vamos a ver como almacenaríamos una llamada a cada uno de ellos, y como finalmente les llamariamos:

```
Func<string> variable = () => Mimetodo("a", "b");
Action variable2 = () => Mimetodo2("a","b");
    
if (opcion == "1") Console.WriteLine(variable());
if (opcion == "1") variable2();
```

Espero que te haya quedado clara esta pequeña explicación.

Comment: Perfecto gracias !

Comment: Sobre este tema, se puede poner un metodo que este en otra clase diferente donde declaras Func ?? Como se haria la referencia?